# Client disconnects immediately (Chrome Extension Websocket Client + NodeJS Server)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am trying to connect with websocket from a chrome 17 extension to a local nodejs server. After creation

var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7055");

After succcessful creation of the websocket instance I receive immediately the onClose event.

A check if websocket is supported is true.

if ("WebSocket" in window) 
     log("Websockets are supported here ");

WHAT IS THE PROBLEM HERE ? I hope anybody can help me with this issue.

The browser is generally able to run websockets, I have tested it
with

http://websocket.org/echo.html

Also the 'Dark WebSocket Terminal' (Google Extension) shows the same
behaviour connecting to ws://localhost:7055/

I tried it also with ws://127.0.0.1:7055/, same result

### client code (Chrome 17 extension)

```
runSockets("ws://localhost:7055");

function runSockets(wsUri) {
if ("WebSocket" in window) 
    log("Websockets are supported here "); 

var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
log("Web Socket created with the state "+ websocket.readyState);

websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
}

function onOpen(evt) {
  log("CONNECTED");
  doSend("WebSocket connected");
}

function onClose(evt) {
  log("DISCONNECTED");
}

function onMessage(evt) {
  log("RESPONSE: " + evt.data);
  websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt) {
  log("ERROR: " + evt.data);
}

function doSend(message {
  log("SENT: " + message); 
  websocket.send(message);
}
```

### server code (nodejs v0.6.11)

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\r\n');
}).listen(7055, 'localhost');

console.log('Server running at http://localhost:7055/');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a websocket server -- what you have in your server is just a regular HTTP server. The most popular is [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), in which case you also need their client (they handle fallbacks for unsupported browsers, and support several websocket versions). [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) is another popular package. [WS](http://einaros.github.com/ws/) is another one. Or `npm search websocket`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a websocket server on the nodejs side such as [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) or [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws). Right now, you are just using nodejs HTTP which will not negotiate websockets.

Once you get socket.io or ws running, be sure to take advantage of reason and code when troubleshooting. E.g.

```
function onClose(evt) {
   log('onclose=>' + ' ' + evt.reason + ', ' + evt.code);   
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you should use [express](http://express.com) and [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) to make your life easier.